# WhereHas with a condition

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, wherehas

I have this relationship in tables.

`consumers;id, name, site_id, tier_id`

`tiers:id, name, site_id`

`categories: id, name, site_id`

`consumer_categories: consumer_id, category_id`

`consumer_tiers: category_id, tier_id`

And this is how I have set it up in models.

Consumer.php

```
public function tier(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Tier::class, 'tier_id');
    }
public function categories(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'consumer_categories', 'consumer_id', 'category_id');
    }
```

Tier.php

```
public function consumers(){
        return $this->hasMany(Consumer::class, 'tier_id');
    }
public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'category_tier', 'tier_id', 'category_id');
    }
```

And Category.php

```
public function consumers(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Consumer::class, 'consumer_categories', 'category_id', 'consumer_id');
    }
```

Now when I run this query with `site_id = 2`

```
$site = Site::find(2);
$consumerQuery = $site->consumers()
            ->whereHas('categories.tiers')
            ->where(function($query) {
                $query->whereNull('tier_status_until')
                    ->orWhere('tier_status_until', '<', date('Y-m-d 00:00:00'))
                ;
            })
        ;
```

It works as expected but when I go to database and manually change one of the `tiers`'s `site_id` to something else the consumer still shows up as if this query isn't validating `site_id = 2`  on `whereHas`

If I write something like this

```
$consumerQuery = $site->consumers()
            ->join('tiers AS t', 't.id', 'consumers.tier_id')
            ->where('t.site_id', '=', $site->id)
            ->where(function($query) {
                $query->whereNull('tier_status_until')
                    ->orWhere('tier_status_until', '<', date('Y-m-d 00:00:00'))
                ;
            })
        ;
```

It works perfectly and doesn't return the consumer who have the tier not associated with `site_id = 2`

Can someone help me fix the `whereHas` ?

Comment: $consumerQuery = $site->consumers()
        ->whereHas('categories.tiers')
        ->where(function($query) {
            $query->whereNull('tier_status_until')
                ->orWhere('tier_status_until', '<', date('Y-m-d 00:00:00'))
            ;
        })
    ; where is site id = 2  in this

Comment: `$site` comes from `$site = Site::find(2)`